# Cosmos DB query strings in array retain grouping and trim the value?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Say we have two sets of data in my collection:

```
{
  "id": "111",
  "linkedId": [
    "ABC:123",
    "ABC:456"
  ]
}
{
  "id": "222",
  "linkedId": [
    "DEF:321",
    "DEF:654"
  ]
}
```

What query can I run to get a result that will look like this?

```
{
  [
    "123",
    "456"
  ]
},
{
  [
    "321",
    "654"
  ]
}
```

I have tried

```
SELECT c.linkedId FROM c
```

But this has the "linkedId" as the property name in the result set. And I tried LEFT but it doesn't trim first 4 characters of the string.

Then I tried

```
SELECT value cc FROM cc In c.linkedId
```

But this loses the grouping.

Any idea?

Comment: hi,Allen,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong, indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are just strings, not json object, i suggest you using [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-udfs) in cosmos db query sql.

UDF:

```
function userDefinedFunction(arr){
    var returnArr = [];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        returnArr.push(arr[i].substring(4,7));
    }
    return returnArr;
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT value udf.test(c.linkedId) FROM c
```

OUTPUT:

[image]